# comment.user is returning #<User:0x007f424ecb36c0> and not the actual readable user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I have _comments.html.erb with the following code

```
  <h3>Comments (<%= commentable.comments.count %>)</h3>
  <% commentable.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.user %><br />
  <span class="timestamp">
  Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago.
  <div class="well">
  <%= comment.body %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

and Commentscontroller

```
@comment = @commentable.comments.new comment_params
@comment.user = current_user
@comment.save
redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Your comment was successfully posted"
```

But

```
#<User:0x007f424ecb36c0>
```

shows up instead of the actual username. how would I go about getting the names of the users displayed properly? I just got done the rails tutorial and I am new to all of this rails stuff. I am trying to add comments to the microposts. Working so far. just not the user information. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Also, when I add name to comment.user I get

```
NoMethodError in MicropostsController#show
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just get the property of the user like this:

```
<%= comment.user.name %>
```

Comment: I am getting `NoMethodError in MicropostsController#show
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass` now after adding comment.user.name

Comment: So you have at least one comment that is not associated to a user, in which case `comment.user` will return `nil`. I guess this is not intended?

Comment: In this case you should probably check the database for those comments and manually delete them if they shouldn't be there in the first place or assign them to the right user. You can also check in the rails console by entering something like: `Comment.where(user: nil)`. This should return the relevant comments and you can update or delete them accordingly. To just quickly fix the error you could call `comment.user.try(:name)`, which will then display an empty string if `user` is `nil`. If `current_user` is `nil` the problem could be that you are not logged in.

Comment: It worked. you were right. I destroyed it. Thank yoU!

Answer (score 2):

You're showing user object instead of username

```
<% comments = commentable.comments %>

 <h3>Comments (<%= comments.count %>)</h3>
    <% comments.each do |comment| %>

      <%= comment.user.name %><br />

      <span class="timestamp">
      Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago.
      <div class="well">
      <%= comment.body %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Just tried that. Apparently comment.user.name is nil. So, that means that current_user must be nil?

Comment: I think it's because there is no value in `user.name`.